# PLS-00201 Error Occured for the Trigger must be declared pls-00201

Tags: oracle, triggers

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_test
AFTER DELETE
ON ADMİN.KULLANICILAR
for each row
DECLARE
    v_username := USER;

BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_username);
END;
```

Hey guys I'm getting that error always I put every privalege to my user and 
it says :

after editing

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_test
AFTER DELETE
ON ADMİN.KULLANICILAR
for each row
DECLARE
    v_username nvarchar2(20) := USER;

BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_username);
END;
```

and error like that it ll runs on apex but not on oracle sql dev:

```
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_username);
END;
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 2, column 26:
PLS-00201: identifier 'V_USERNAME' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 2, column 5:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Comment: Why do you use `SELECT user INTO v_username FROM dual;`? Just write `v_username := USER;` or even `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(USER);`

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_test
AFTER DELETE
ON KULLANICILAR
for each row
DECLARE
    v_username := USER;

BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_username);
END;


im getting same error

Comment: Please run `alter session set nls_language = english;` in order to get english error messages.

Comment: BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_username);
END;
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 2, column 26:
PLS-00201: identifier 'V_USERNAME' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 2, column 5:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Comment: Please don't put additional information as comment, edit your question instead.

Comment: Ok help me please

Comment: Is this your real error message, resp. your real code? You should get an `PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following: ...`

Comment: A variable declaration needs a data type: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-language-fundamentals.html#GUID-568AC23F-1BC3-444E-855E-BF2EC4EEB14B

Comment: Error `ORA-06550: line 2, column 26:
PLS-00201: identifier 'V_USERNAME' must be declared` does not match to your code. Run `show errors` in order to get PL/SQL compilation error.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are doing to get your error as I can create that trigger against one of my own tables and it compiles and functions as expected.